# would even Cersei be so mad = was?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

*Clash of Kings by George R. R. Martin*

> " [...] They are bastards. The girl as well. All three of them
> abominations born of incest.”
>
> **Would** even Cersei **be** so mad? Catelyn was speechless.

Martin writes about Cersei [the queen] having three children who are not highborn. Cersei is married to the king, but the king is not the father.

Does **"would be"** mean **"was"** in this context? If this is the case, is used to express *uncertainty*?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Despite the fact that Cersei is renowned for being insane, this state of affairs is outrageous even by her standards."

Literally: "Could it be possible that Cersei was so insane that even she would do something so beyond belief?"

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I change it to "Was even Cersei so mad?" Or does this change the meaning?

Comment: Then it asks a direct question of her current state of insanity. "Would be" implies that it is not possible or feasible to establish her level of insanity, so it is posed as a hypothetical, indeed, rhetorical, question.

Comment: so just to make it clear. Would be = was + uncertainty?

Comment: No, it's more subtle than just "uncertainty". "was" expresses uncertainty, "would be" expresses the belief that the question is going to remain uncertain.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I need to google for the rule or something on this topic

Comment: Would anyone be so mad as to play with matches while standing in a pool of gasoline?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yep, a good example of "would" being used in the rhetorical-question context.